# How to add 'add to cart' button in custom content type using Commerce 2?

Tags: 8, commerce

I have created a new content type with product title, description, price(field_price), SKU(field_sku) fields. I just want to add a <kbd>Add to cart</kbd> button into this content type.

What I tried?
I have read many places, it says to add 'Product references'. I have tried to do that using 'Entity reference' field and selected 'Product'. But no luck.

Can someone guide me step by step about how can we add such 'Add to cart' button in custom content type?

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps to show <kbd>Add to cart</kbd> button into any content type.

1. Add field with reference as Product and select list of product bundles you want to show in content type.
2. And in field settings select reference as shown in below.
   [image]
3. Go to content type manage display and select as "Rendered Entity" as shown below.
   [image]
4. Go to the product type which you selected in content type and click on manage display.
5. See for variations and select as "Add to cart form" as shown in below.
   [image]

And that's it after adding node with product you will be able to see the <kbd>Add to cart</kbd> button into node view like below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!, 

Now I am getting 'Add to cart' button. But I should able to add price while creating the node. Now price is getting from the product page and cannot add price while creating the node. Basically every node should act as product with different price.

Comment: For single product you want different prices to display in each node?

Comment: Each node different prices. For example: I have a content type 'Toys'. I have to create many Toys contents with different price and other details.

Comment: You have to add "Product Variations" for this to each product. Cannot add the price for each node.

Comment: Ok, I don't want any predefined prices. Price should be always free text. Any options for this?

Comment: As per my suggestion after adding the product to the node and display the price in the node, while adding the product to cart you can modify the price of the product and add it to cart. There are ways to alter the price of a product while adding cart you can check with that.